# html - input tag limit to alphabets and number

Tags: regex, html

How do I set an `input` tag to only take alphabets and numbers? I don't want punctuations and the rest.

I tried this:

```
<input maxlength="12" v-model="profile.name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]">
```

But it did not work. I can still put in punctuation like `!@#$` and all.

Comment: The pattern should be `[0-9A-Za-z]*`, but I also can't get this to work using a demo.

Comment: yup, this not working.

Answer (score 2):

The expression is checked on the form submit. So you have to place a form element for the check

```html
<form action="/x.php">
  Random:<input maxlength="12" v-model="profile.name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want, but you did give me the idea that since I am using `vue`, I can `watch` the `profile.name` as user key in. Thanks!

Comment: oh you never mentioned vue on your OP. Glad that it worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

You could look at:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onblur_onfocus
You ca/should write a small function to check on illegal/not allowed characters.
You can extend the use by passing a type of check, so you can check for wrong emailaddresses, not allowed characters, empty fields etc.
'

Comment: Yup, that is one way to do it. Since I am using `vue`, I can just `watch` the variable as user key in.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead [^A-Za-z0-9-_ ]

Comment: unfortunately still can put punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the regex:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

This will allow only alphanumeric. and since I use `vue.js`, I will use `watch` to monitor the variable:

```
'profile': {
  handler: function(newVal, oldVal) {
   var self = this;
   var regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
   if (!regex.test(newVal.name)) {
      console.log("character not allow!");
   }
  },
  deep: true
 }
```